# Converse in inclusion problem of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Show that the relation $(A\cup C)\subset (A\cup B)$ and $(A\cap C)\subset (A\cap B)$, when combined, imply $C\subset B$. Disprove the *converse* by an example.

I have a problem of proving that the *converse* is wrong. In fact i find that the converse is true.

I am assuming the *converse* is just that $C\subset B$ *does imply* the previous two conditions combined.

Comment: Note that the comparison operator is $\subset$, not $\subseteq$. What if $A=C\cup B$? $A=\varnothing$?

Comment: The converse of "A implies B" is "B implies A", not "B does not imply A". "B does not imply A" is the negation of the converse. It's not strange that you have a problem, because what you think is the converse is the negation of the converse!

Comment: Does $\subset$ stand for inclusion or strict inclusion?

Comment: @Don, thanks. I was assuming $\subset$ is used here meaning $\subseteq$.

Comment: Taroccoesbrocco, after @Don $\subset$ should not mean $\subseteq $, meaning strict. Taking $A = \emptyset$ disprove the Converse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first one, let B be empty and C ...
For the second one, let C and A be disjoint and ...